# Валидатор отказывается проверять файл css

Tags: css, bootstrap

Загружаю в validator.w3.org файл стилей css, нажимаю на "check", а он отвечает "Sorry! This document cannot be checked." Проблема возникает уже второй раз на этой неделе. В прошлый раз я просто повторил это действие спустя пару часов и он проверил файл. Текст ошибки - на скриншоте.[image: Скриншот ошибки валидатора] . Также привожу ниже фрагмент проверяемого css-файла (это стилизация шапки сайта).[image: Фрагмент css-файла]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Этот валидатор в принципе никогда и не был предназначен для проверки css

Comment: Здравствуйте! А какой лучше использовать?

Comment: Тот, который предназначен https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Большое спасибо, andreymal!